# iphone caching issue - UISearchbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I have an app which uses a dynamic forward search using UISearchBar

Here is what it does..I have 2 views; A (List) & B (Detail)

On View A, I have a UISearchBar where the user can type anything and the list below gets updated dynamically (uses copied arrays) i.e. from an external web service API

Say a scenario, user has to type "WORD"
He'll start with W
So list will show "WA","WB","WC","WD", etc
Now he'll type 2nd letter O (so search term now is "WO")
So list will display "WO1","WO2","WO3", etc

At the point where user has typed WO and he clicks on one of the options in the list say WO2, he'll be taken to details abt WO2
He clicks back from there...So again he is shown WO1, WO2, WO3, ...

Now here is my question..if he now clicks on WO1, even though the list is showing WO1, WO2, WO3, ...he is taken to details about "WA" (i.e. first item in the previous list (i.. at the time of typing 'W' only)

So there seems to be some caching abt the previous index value, it seems...
Could you please help me with the issue.

I am using array for most of the things. search result, pushing detail, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, provide code for main list's DataSource and for UISearchDisplayController's DataSource.

It seems that in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you're getting wrong object and send it to details controller.

Anyway, you must switch between tableViews in your list view controller to get right object for indexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if (aTableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) 
    {
        //  configure cell for object from filtered by keyword list
    }
    else
    {
        //  configure cell for object from unfiltered list
    }   
}

- (void)tabeView:(UITableVIew *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // get object according to cell and push it to details controller
}
```

Comment: The code that you have provided is along the lines or almost exact to what I have..See the issue is I do not get the wrong detail view always...It is inconsistent..So one time I might get correct detail page and 2nd time , entirely diff.

Comment: Source code for this issue would be helpful. How did you get objects to show in filtered list?

Comment: I have now tried with 2 diff ways and still face the same issue;
1. Using global var in App Delegate
2. Using a shared instance (Singleton)

In both cases, the app crashes during multiple back/forth between list/detail...The list being filled using the 2 ways I have told above. I really don't know where to look now. Please help me...

Comment: Can you edit your question to make source code a little bit more readable?